# Zend Framework Breadcrumb show invisible elements

Tags: zend-framework, navigation, element, breadcrumbs, invisible

I have a Navigation bar in my site and i have visible and invisible elements. I did that by defining the tag "visible" in my navigation.xml. My problem is that when I want to make breadcrumb using that same navigation I need to also display the "not visible" elements, is there a way to do this??.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your xml as well as code that you use for navigation and/or breadcrumbs.

Answer (score 6):

Try setting renderInvisible flag as follows:

```
<?php echo $this->navigation()->breadcrumbs()->setRenderInvisible(true); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting setRenderInvisible(true), you may want to disable a link for the page itself:

```
$visible = !empty($this->id);

$breadCrumbs = $this->navigation('navigation')->breadcrumbs()
    ->setLinkLast($visible) // link last page
    ->setSeparator(' /' . PHP_EOL)
    ->setRenderInvisible(true)
;
```

This is helpful if the page requires an id. The last link in the bread crumbs will not include additional parameters such as an id.